# How can I force shell to push an object after self destroying with delay (Unity3D)

Tags: game-engine, unity-game-engine

I have an object inside a boundary and I shoot into the object (to understand my code see this lesson: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/creating-hazards?playlist=17147). Shell (bullet) should be destroyed after collision with object, but not instantly - after some delay (i.e. they collides and after some amount of seconds shell disappears). Shell's collider should be with a trigger, but because of it she flies through the object. Shell should disappear after it affected the object. I made the delay in order to have time for affecting.  But if there a way it can disappear instantly then that's great. I just wanted give time to shell to apply a force.

```
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
     if (other.tag == "Boundary") 
     {
         return;
     }
     //Destroy (gameObject);
     StartCoroutine(WaitAndDestroy());
    }
    IEnumerator WaitAndDestroy() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: What is moving the bullet?  Whatever it is, you need to turn it off when in this state.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain done

Comment: How large are colliders for these objects?  Sometimes objects can 'slip' through each other undetected if the colliders are not large enough.

Comment: Is the thing that is going wrong that you want it to bounce off the object? Or perhaps you see it bouncing off of the object instead of going through it like you want?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain you understood me right, yes it disappears after collision, but collision doesn't affect the object - shell flies through. It should push it and then disappear.

Comment: Do you want the bullet to "Push" the object it hits (like a person leaning in to and pushing a box along the floor), or do you want the bullet to "hit" the object (like two balls thrown at each other in the air and they bounce off each other)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I want how it was before: shell pushing an object, the object is bounced, after that the shell follows the same trajectory (flying behind the object).

Comment: I think I have a solution but I won't be able to write up an answer till I get to my computer that has Unity and that won't be till tonight. Basically, when the collision happens you need to add a `Force` to the object you hit as you pass through it.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain strange solution. Still isn't clear why delaying affects bouncing of the object.

Comment: Delaying does not affect it, the fact you made your collider a `Trigger` instead of a normal collider is what causes it to not bounce off. Trigger colliders pass through other objects without affecting them or them affecting you, they only cause a event to be raised in code. So you must, in that raised event (`OnTriggerEnter`), do the work a non trigger collider would have done to push the hit object. This lets you go through the object but still "push" it as you go through.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to happen to the shells direction once it hits a object. Should it bounce off or pass through and continue moving forward? I understand you want the object hit to go backwards, but what happens to the shell?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain shell should disappear after it affected the object. I made the delay in order to have time for affecting.

Comment: You said "Shell (bullet) should be destroyed after collision with object, but not instantly - after some delay" How does the bullet behave in the time between the hit and it's destruction. From your last comment it seems like you want it to disappear instantly, but your question says there should be a delay.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain the main thing is affecting (the object should be moved away), if shell can disappear instantly that's great. I just wanted give time to shell to apply a force.

Comment: Forces don't use time, they are applied instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `StartCoroutine(WaitAndDestroy());` above the `return` statement.

Comment: It's awesome that you spotted the problem.  But, please, **there is a huge problem with clutter here on SO with the Unity3D tag**.  The result will be that no questions will be answered on Unity3D here - everyone will just ignore the tag as trash.  This question should certainly be closed ("simple typographical error" reason is best). One idea with such trivial QA is just mention the problem in a comment, and click "Close". You get points for closing questions that should be closed.

Comment: @Pawel Marecki it seems you have no idea how this code works, because your proposition makes no sense. But nevertheless I tried - as I expected it does nothing useful.

Comment: @JoeBlow are you saying that Unity3d questions should be taken elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Rickest, no *this particular question* is too trivial

Comment: With the new information from the OP this answer is nolonger relevant. The OP's problem is he is using a trigger collider instead of a normal collider.

Comment: @Joe Blow explain please.

Comment: @GeorgeJ the question was trivial but you had a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you asked about destroying your game object (which was a trival problem), but your real problem you want solved is that your bullet is not moving the object it is colliding with (which is a much more complex problem to solve)

Comment: The question - like 50% of Unity3D tags on here - needs to be closed.  Firstly, it should be instantly closed as unclear.  Secondly, instantly closed as a typo. Thirdly, instantly closed as a zillion-times dupe of "open manual to trigger"

Comment: @Joe Blow Why answer should be closed because of typo, instead of fixing someone's typo ? I know what you mean about triggers, but this doesn't solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is nesessary to use `OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)`, and put `Destroy(other.gameObject)` into it. And colliders should be without triggers - on both interacting objects.

Comment: You can still use a single collider, just move your code from `OnTriggerEnter` to `OnColliderEnter` and make sure your colider is NOT in "trigger mode"

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain indeed thanks, will you write a new answer or I should add this to my ?

Comment: Just add it to yours

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain sorry, mistake, you solution doesn't work

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain you probably wanted to say OnCollisionEnter, it works then.

Comment: As I said, I was not near a computer with Unity so I coulden't test. Yes, I ment OnCollisionEnter, I coped the wrong name from the online documentation